# findstr or grep output to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, grep, findstr

Im in Windows Server 2003 and using below commands to fetch string matching lines in files created today in a specific directory.

```
forfiles -p D:\ -m *.1  -d +0 -c "cmd /c findstr /i /c:\"Hey Hi\" @FILE" >> txt5.txt
or
forfiles -p D:\ -m *.1  -d +0 -c "cmd /c grep \"Hey Hi\" @FILE" >> txt5.txt
```

Geeting error 'FINDSTR: Write error' and 'grep write error bad file descriptor' respectively for both commands. So basically the commands work i.e. display the output in screen but unable to redirect the output to a file.

I did not find suitable solution though users reported this same error for different scenarios.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work as a batch?  ie, `processX.bat >> txt5.txt` or `call processX.bat >> txt5.txt`

Comment: @AustinSalonen I placed those commands inside process.bat/process.cmd. Now I called process.bat from another batch file ie process >> txt5.txt. It is writing the commands to the txt5.txt but not its output!

Comment: @KenWhite not sure why but removing cmd /c like in your command did the trick. The error vanished and Im now able to write the output to a file. You can delete your comment and paste it as an answer so that I can acknowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to remove the `cmd /c`; I don't see any reason you'd need a new copy of the command shell open for the `findstr` call.

This works for me correctly at the command prompt:

```
forfiles -m t*.xml -d +0 -c "findstr /i "Item" @file" >> out.txt.
```

It produces an `out.txt` file that contains the proper content matching the search criteria.